# How to change primary node type in service fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How would you go about changing the SKU of a VMSS (in particular the primary node type) without bringing the entire VMSS down?

I tried setting upgrade mode to Manual

```
$vmss.UpgradePolicy.Mode = [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.UpgradeMode]::Manual
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name  $VMScaleSetName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

Which just ended up with:

> Virtual Machine Scale Sets with extension
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode cannot be set to
>   manual upgrade mode

Ignoring that and just doing an upgrade

```
$vmss.Sku.Name = "Standard_A2_V2";
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMScaleSetName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

Instead brought down all nodes simultaneously. So what is the recommended approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you have configured durability level 'Gold' or 'Silver'. (Silver is not available yet though)

More on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity#the-durability-characteristics-of-the-cluster).

Comment: So currently only Gold. It doesnt say _how_ though. Is it fully automatic?

Comment: My understanding is that ASF can postpone infrastructural changes to the underlying VM's. So when a VMSS node sku changes, those changes will be sequentially applied per UD (random order), instead of all in parallel. So from your perspective it's fully automatic.